# Compare 2 Json strings using Junit5 and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, jackson, mockito, junit5

I have the below Junit.i am trying to test compare if both Json string have same fields (order and value is not important). My test keep getting failed with below error

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected:
> <{"person_id":0,"person_name":null}> but was:
> <{"person_id":0,"person_name":null}

```
@Test 
  void inputpojo_test() throws Exception {
  
  String path = "src/test/data/json_file.txt";
  String jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
  
   Input i = new Input();
  
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
  String bean =objectMapper.writeValueAsString(i);
  
  assertEquals(bean,jsonString); 
 }
```

json_file.txt is `{"person_id":0,"person_name":null}` and Input class is

```
@JsonProperty("person_id") //getters and setter ommited for brevity
     int id;
    
    @JsonProperty("person_name")
     String name ;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    String value ;
```

Comment: there is no guarantee that the keys will be written in the same order, so comparing json strings is pointless. Compare nodes instead, using `valueToTree` and `readTree`

Comment: @njzk2 i can get away with ordering by using JsonOrder annotation in the Input class.But i guess using `valueToTree` is a better test for this

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not to use raw string comparison at all
(as it is done inside JUnit's `assertEquals`).

Instead you should use a library which compares the
expected and actual JSON on a logical level
(i.e. ignoring white-space and sequence of properties).
For more info see [jsonassert.skyscreamer.org](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org) and [Baeldung - Introduction to JSONassert](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert).

Using this library you would compare the two JSON strings not by

```
assertEquals(bean, jsonString, true);
```

but instead by

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(bean, jsonString, true);
```

Then you would get an assertion error only in case of "real" differences.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing json, it's best to use a semantic comparison, rather than a string comparison. This can allow you to handle minor formatting issues, and even things being in different orders.

You could use ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert

Example

```java
assertJson(bean).isEqualTo(jsonString);
```

Other libraries like JSONAssert also exist.

Answer (score 1):

try using `trim()` before comparing

```
assertEquals(bean.trim(),jsonString.trim());
```

Here is also some dangerous trap as **njzk2** noted in comments. It works with `trim()` because Jackson uses the JsonProperties in the order declared in your bean and some empty spaces existed in one or both of those strings.

However this is not safe for future releases. Try to compare actual Objects instead of Strings

```
String path = "src/test/data/json_file.txt";
String jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
Person bean1 =objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);

Input i = new Input();
Person bean2 =objectMapper.readValue(i, Person.class);
  
assertEquals(bean1, bean2); 
 }
```

Also in YourClass don't forget to override `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` methods for compares based on class fields.

Comment: yeah probably empty spaces which don't get printed in the message because it is already trimmed in output

Comment: json standard doesn't specify key orders, or spaces between tokens, so 2 strings can represent the same object but not be equal